# How to get the elevation of each point of KML file

Tags: here-api

I have specific route, represented by 100 and more points (classic KML file, for example http://dropbox.com/s/4k1bx3fl3p6h3tj/as-sokolov.kml?dl=1). In this case, I don't need to generate route, but just want to get elevation of any points. Is it possible? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you will have to use the Fleet Telematics API to retrieve advanced data (layers). The ADAS_ATTRIB_FC1...5 layer contains curvature, height and slope information for all FC1 to FC5 roads.
https://developer.here.com/documentation/fleet-telematics/dev_guide/topics/here-map-content.html

You can get the layer content, given a bounding box or a polyline.
https://developer.here.com/documentation/fleet-telematics/api-reference.html#operation%2FsearchCorridorUsingGET